# Get value from an array in a map based on a key in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe with the following schema:

```
 |-- A: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: array (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- index: boolean (nullable = false)
 |-- idkey: string (nullable = true)
```

Since the value in the map is of type array, I need to extract the field index corresponding to the id in the "foreign" key field idkey.

For example, I have the following data:

```
 {"A":{
 "innerkey_1":[{"id":"1","type":"0.01","index":true},
               {"id":"6","type":"4.3","index":false}]},
 "1"}
```

Since the idkey is 1, we need to to output the value of index corresponding to the element where `"id":1`, i.e. the index should be equal to true. I am really not sure how I can accomplish this, with UDFs or otherwise.

Expected output is:

```
+---------+
| indexout|
+---------+
|   true  |
+---------+
```

Comment: can you clarify `i.e. the index should be equal to 0` ?? and can you share your expected output too

Comment: and how can 1 be a boolean value? and type struct seems to be double not string. ??

Comment: I have fixed the typos, thanks for pointing them out.

Comment: index false has id 6 . they don't match idkey with id. the matching index should be true.

Comment: aren't these `Since the idkey is 1, we need to to output the value of index corresponding to the element where "id":1, i.e. the index should be equal to false` contradicting with each other?

Comment: You are right again. I apologize for being sloppy with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your *dataframe* has following `schema`

```
root
 |-- A: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: array (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- types: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- index: boolean (nullable = false)
 |-- idkey: string (nullable = true)
```

then you can `use two explode function`, one for the `map` and other for the inner `array`, use a `filter` to filter the match and finally `select` the index as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.select(col("idkey"), explode(col("A")))
  .select(col("idkey"), explode(col("value")).as("value"))
  .filter(col("idkey") === col("value.id"))
  .select(col("value.index").as("indexout"))
```

You should get

```
+--------+
|indexout|
+--------+
|true    |
+--------+
```

**Using udf function**

You can do the above by using a `udf` function which would avoid the two `explode` and a `filter` too. *all of the explodes and filter is done in udf function itself*. You can modify according to your needs.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def indexoutUdf = udf((a: Map[String, Seq[Row]], idkey: String) => {
  a.map(x => x._2.filter(y => y.getAs[String](0) == idkey).map(y => y.getAs[Boolean](2))).toList(0).head
})
df.select(indexoutUdf(col("A"), col("idkey")).as("indexout")).show(false)
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Is there a way to do it other than using explode? I considered it but it will be too expensive for large dataframes.

Comment: @PramodKumar, I have updated the answer :) I hope the answer is going to be upvoted and accepted this time ;)